# Detect first connect of persistent PHP stream (STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT)

Tags: php, networking

I want to use **stream_socket_client** with option **STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT** for stateful protocol. So some data exchange should be done upon TCP connection only (e.g.authentication).

Can I distinguish whether stream returned by **stream_socket_client** is a 'new born' or it's reused one?

I'm talking about php-fpm, so using of some global variables to store stream state is not an option, and usage of PHP sessions is to complicated, I guess.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I use following workaround (yes, I know it's ugly...):

```
$chunk = stream_set_chunk_size($stream, 8193);
if ($chunk == 8193)
    //it's existing connection, newborn has other value (8192 mostly)
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ftell](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php), if it returns more than `0`, then it's a reused connection.